# Integration of SSRS reports on Sharepoint 2010

Tags: reporting-services, sharepoint-2010, ssrs-2008

I have developed SSRS reports and deployed on sharepoint 2010 document library. But when I tried to open it on sharepoint, it is not showing me report, Just showing loading popup.
I have checked report property as well as report credential. 
What more I have to check to show my reports on sharepoint.
I am new in sharepoint as well as SSRS report. I hope that, I explained my question properly. Please give me your valuable suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

here is good article that demonstrates step by step guidelines to ssrs reports and deployed on sharepoint 2010 document library.

http://fendy-huang.blogspot.in/2011/02/create-ssrs-report-with-sharepoint-2010.html

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I have done in way you suggested but when I click on "Report Builder Report", it is not responding. It just loading.